# Evaluating and proving the limit of a function from the irrational to the real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

> The Problem: If $f: D \to \mathbb{R}$, with $D = \{x\mid x \text{ is irrational}\}$ and $$f(x)=\frac{2x}{x-3}$$ evaluate 
>   $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$$ and then prove your result.  Only use the definition of the definition of the limit of a function, and the definition of a limit of a function tending to infinity.

This seems simple enough to evaluate.  The limit as $x$ approaches infinity is $2$, but I'm not sure what is being restricted by making the domain all $x$ such that $x$ is irrational.

Comment: How do you know that the limit is 2?

Comment: Since the numerator and the denominator have the same highest degree of x, the coefficients of x are the limit.  I know I can't prove it based on that idea.

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove this in two steps :

1. For every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $M \in \mathbb{R}_+$ such that, if $x > M$, then
   $$
   \left | \frac{2x}{x-3} - 2 \right | < \epsilon
   $$
   Proof : Note that
   $$
   \left | \frac{2x}{x-3} - 2 \right | < \epsilon \Leftrightarrow -\epsilon < \frac{6}{x-3} < \epsilon
   $$
   $$
   \Leftrightarrow 3 - 6/\epsilon > x > 3 + 6/\epsilon
   $$
   Now can you find $M$?
2. Now for $\epsilon > 0$, find $M$ as in (1), and choose $N \in \mathbb{Q}^c$ such that $N > M$, then if $x \in D$, $x>N$, then
   $$
   \left | \frac{2x}{x-3} - 2 \right | < \epsilon
   $$
   Hence, $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)  = 2$

All you need here is that, for every $M \in \mathbb{R}$, there is a $N \in \mathbb{Q}^c$ such that $N>M$.

Comment: I would say that M < 3+6/e

Comment: You want $M = 3+6/\epsilon$ (or anything bigger)!